# How to combine nearly identical custom rewrite rules for WordPress

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, regex

I have 22 rewrite rules in my functions.php. I was wondering if it is possible to combine some of the nearly identical rewrite rules.

1. Combining identical rewrite rules for different PAGES:

```
'^videos/sort/([^/]+)/?$',
'index.php?pagename=videos&sort=$matches[1]',

'^actors/sort/([^/]+)/?$',
'index.php?pagename=actors&sort=$matches[1]',
```

->something like:
'^videos (OR) actors/sort/([^/]+)/?$',

2. Combining rewrite rules for a PAGE named "cars"
   Both rewrites are for the same page and use query var "sort", but some pages also use query var "p")

```
'^cars/sort/([^/]+)/?$',
'index.php?pagename=cars&sort=$matches[1]',

'^cars/sort/([^/]+)/p/([^/]+)/?$',
'index.php?pagename=cars&sort=$matches[1]&p=$matches[2]',
```

Can these be combined with a condition like:
'^cars/sort/([^/]+)/ AND OPTIONAL p/([^/]+)/ ?$',

3. Combining rewrite rules for CUSTOM POST TYPE "actor"
   The rewrites have either custom query vars "p", "sort", or both of them in the url.

```
'^actor/([^/]+)/p/(\d+)/?$',
'index.php?actor=$matches[1]&p=$matches[2]',

'^actor/([^/]+)/sort/([^/]+)/?$',
'index.php?actor=$matches[1]&sort=$matches[2]',

'^actor/([^/]+)/sort/([^/]+)/p/(\d+)/?$',
'index.php?actor=$matches[1]&sort=$matches[2]&p=$matches[3]',
```